# Why would instruction latency increase from a previous CPU generation?

Tags: cpu

Namely interested in why Intel doubled the latency of their shift instructions from Ivy Bridge to Haswell, as documented [here](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/haswell_(client)#CPU_changes), but other cases are also interesting.

Answer (score 1):

They may not have intended to increase it, but instead may have been forced to increase it due to other architectural improvements or changes.

A modern CPU is a monumentally massive collection of combinational and sequential logic and at high clock speeds you have a problem with trace lengths actually being a limiting factor in how fast you can do something.

Moving one operational part of the core closer to another might mean pushing a third part slightly further away, thus leading to a slight increase in the time taken to ensure the data is "there" and settled before triggering that unit to do their work.

As a result improving performance in one area might mean a loss in another. Adding instructions or optimising routing might also result in sub-optimal routing for other parts.

It is unlikely that someone said "you know what, no one uses this. Let's bump it up to 4 clocks." Chances are it was a design meeting that said "Look, we want to add `x` & `y`, move `z` and the problem is this dude here. Can we move him and take a small hit to performance? Will the benefits outweigh the loss?"

Sometime reliability of a bit of circuitry also means giving it a little more time to do its job.